# How the whole domain name and DNS works?

Tags: dns, domain

Recently I'm considering setup my own website.

So first thing occurs to me is that I need to get a domain name. And I should somehow publish that for this domain name, point to my server.
Now some questions occur to me:

1. How does a domain registrar guarantee that the domain I purchase won't be used by others ??
2. I can understand that domain registrar is some kind of distributer of domain names controled by the ICANN organization. What I can't understand is after I buy a domain, how can I tell all the dns servers on the internet that for this domain, please point to this server.

Comment: This is a way to broad question to answer. And it does not fit the site which is a practical 'how do I solve problem X' site. Instead the question is 'explain to me the whole concept and setup off. For which a book might be a better starting place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after I buy a domain, how can I tell all the dns servers on the internet that for this domain, please point to this server

You don't need to tell all DNS servers, just the ones that are *authoritative* for the parent domain. Much like with websites, the DNS information for any given domain is only hosted in a few servers (usually 2–3 for smaller domains, maybe 8–12 for TLDs).

Everyone else – for example, *resolvers* like 8.8.8.8 – merely contact the authoritative servers if you ask them about a domain that's not in the cache yet.

So if you buy `example.com.`, you only need to inform the servers which host the `com.` domain. (And you don't do that manually – your registrar does that for you, by contacting the registry that operates `com.`. Sometimes those are actually the same company, even.)

Then,

> How does a domain registrar guarantee that the domain I purchase won't be used by others

The simplest way is, you create an account on the registrar's website, and it only lets the correct account change the associated domain's parameters.